# Why did my answer become community wiki?

Tags: bug, status-bydesign

I have just had [an answer](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/a/20793/17082) marked as community wiki after I edited it *once*. What's going on? Is this deliberate?

Comment: se rules re [community wiki](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11740/what-are-community-wiki-posts/11741#11741)

Comment: @Kaveh vzn's link points out that moderators can un-CW a post that was made so because of edit count. Can this be done in this case? (Ditto for the answers.)

Comment: @David, yes, mods can do that (though we normally don't do it as it is quite a pain to do this every time a question and its answers becomes CW).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It became CW because [Mohammad edited his question and it became CW because of the number of edits](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/posts/20780/revisions) and when a question becomes CW all its new answers become CW also automatically.

Comment: Ah. Thanks. That's a pretty ridiculous "feature".

Comment: CW is left mostly untouched since SE 1.0. I think SE is working on changing how CW works as they did for closing and faq/help page.